# Mosaic fails when reading rasters from disc but not from memory

Tags: r, r-raster, r-mosaic

I ran into a weird issue when trying to make a mosaic from several hundred rasters. The satellite imagery I'm using is not perfectly aligned or shares the exact same resolution, so I followed the steps found [here](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/createrasterimagemosaic) to resample my rasters and then mosaic them.

I started off testing on a subset of only four images and had no problem doing this (had to manually calculate the full extent since `unionExtent` and the newer `union` only allows two extent arguments):

```
# Reading raster files
rst <- lapply(list.files(), FUN = stack)

# Extracting individual extents
rst_ext <- lapply(rst, FUN =  extent)

# Calculating full extent
xmin_rst <- c(); xmax_rst <- c(); ymin_rst <- c(); ymax_rst <- c();
for (i in 1:length(rst_ext)) {
    xmin_rst <- c(xmin_rst, rst_ext[[i]]@xmin)
    ymin_rst <- c(ymin_rst, rst_ext[[i]]@ymin)
    xmax_rst <- c(xmax_rst, rst_ext[[i]]@xmax)
    ymax_rst <- c(ymax_rst, rst_ext[[i]]@ymax)
}
full_extent <- extent(min(xmin_rst), max(xmax_rst),
                      min(ymin_rst), max(ymax_rst))

# Creating raster from full extent and first rasters' CRS and resolution
bounding_rst <- raster(full_extent, 
                   crs = crs(rst[[1]]),
                   res = res(rst[[1]]))

# Resampling rasters to match attributes of the bounding raster
rst_resampled <- lapply(X = rst, fun = function(x) {
    target_rst <- crop(bounding_rst, x)
    resample(x, target_rst, method="bilinear")
})

# Creating mosaic
rst_mosaic <- do.call("mosaic", c(rst_resampled, fun = mean))
```

That worked out OK, but of course, I didn't want to save all those rasters in my memory since I'd run out of it. I decided to save them in a new folder and re-read them as a `stack`, then make the mosaic.

```
# Function to crop, resample and write to a new GeoTIFF
resample_write <- function(x) {
  target_rst <- crop(bounding_rst, x)
  x <- resample(x, target_rst, method="bilinear")
  save_name <- gsub("\\.1", 
                    "_resampled.tif", 
                    names(x)[1]) # Modifying name of 1st band
  writeRaster(x,
              filename = paste("../testing_resampling/", 
                               save_name, sep = ""),
              format = "GTiff")
}

# Running the function
lapply(rst, FUN = resample_write)

# Reading resampled images
setwd("../testing_resampling/")
rst_resampled2 <- lapply(list.files(), FUN = stack)

## Making the mosaic
rst_mosaic2 <- do.call("mosaic", c(rst_resampled2, fun = mean))
```

This gives the following error:

```
> rst_mosaic2 <- do.call("mosaic", c(rst_resampled2, fun = mean))
Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different origin
```

I was able to get around it by setting the increasing the tolerance argument of `mosaic` to `0.4` but still don't understand why `rst_resampled1` and `rst_resampled2` yield different `mosaic` results.

Comparing them both with `compareRaster` and `cellStats` tells me that they're exactly the same.